# Need to implement one user can login on one machine one browser at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

## Scenario:

1. User X1 logged in. He can not be logged again. up to previous log out. In this case it should give message that this user is logged at diff place. pLease logout and try to login again.
2. If user closes browser then it should be logged out automatically.
3. Session should never expire as i logged in.

---

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: A better question would outline your approach and ask for feedback. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Did u get my Scenario for implementation. I am asking best possible solution for it.

Comment: i have tried using cookies then maintain user status in sql on login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are asking to prevent multiple logins. If so, you seriously need to read a lot. please go through this link:

[Preventing Multiple Logins in ASP.NET](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030418.asp)

and

[Prevent Multiple Logins Using the Cache in ASP.NET](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030416.asp)

Comment: Tried same thing and using Inproc session and managing all setting insqlserver. thanks for suggestion i vl tried it surly.

Comment: use StateServer session mode for your third issue mentioned in your question. I'm not saying session will never expire but this is more reliable than Inproc. read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column for the table(which contains user data) which holds the user status *logged* or *logged* out which you can update as use login  and login out.

You can always the check status from the table when  you needs